# Proper workflow to manipulate a raster to match the extent, origin, and resolution of another

Tags: r, raster

I'm working with two rasters that differ in their origin, extent, and resolution. I have a bathymetry raster, with a higher resolution (x=0.0008333333, y=0.0008333333) and a MUCH great spatial extent. I also have a sea surface temperature raster, which has a much coarser resolution (x=0.04166667, y=0.04166667). Both rasters have the same projection (longlat, datum=WGS84).

I would like to manipulate the bathymetry raster to match the extent, origin, and resolution of the sea surface temperature raster. However, I have very little experience and I am uncertain of the 'best practices.'

I have tried two different methods, and I would like to know which is better, and maybe an explanation of how they differ in terms of the underlying processes. I'm also open to other methods that might be better at preserving the data.

Method 1:
1) first, I aggregated the bathymetry raster to make it as similar to the SST raster as possible

```
library(raster)
bathycoarse<-aggregate(bathymetry, fact=c(48,50), fun=mean)
```

2) second, I cropped the bathymetry raster by the SST raster

```
bathycoarsecrop<-crop(bathycoarse,sst)
```

3) third, I resampled the bathymetry raster using the SST raster, resulting in the same origin and extent.

```
bathyresample<-resample(bathycoarsecrop, sst, method="bilinear")
```

Method 2: I used the function projectRaster()

```
bathy2<-projectRaster(bathymetry, sst, method="bilinear")
```

Obviously, method 2 is much simpler. But I don't really understand what the function is doing, so I want to make sure I am accomplishing my goal in the correct method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "projectRaster" function uses the same resampling as the "resample" function (the resampling method is defined by the "method" argument you set to "bilinear" - indicating bilinear interpolation, which is probably what you want when your dealing with continuous numeric datasets). 
So using the function should just work fine for you.

If you want to speed things up, you can easily use paralell processing with the "projectRaster" function by starting a cluster with the "beginCluster" function, which then allows automatic parallel processing with the "projectRaster" function.

```
beginCluster(4) # use the number of cores you want to use
bathy2 <- projectRaster(bathymetry, sst, method="bilinear")
endCluster()
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I used projectRaster(), and I noticed something strange. I made a data frame so that I could compare the sea surface temperature values and the bathymetry values at each pixel (now that both have the same coordinate system, extent, and cell size). both rasters have 'NA' values that correspond to landmasses. I noticed that some of the pixels have 'NA' values for bathymetry, but numeric values for SST. how can this be? the original bathymetry raster had a very fine resolution than the SST raster, so its outline of the landmasses should be accurate